# How can I combine multiple javascript fuctions into one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to combine these 4 javascript functions into one. They are exactly the same, just targeting a different ID on line 8. It's being used for the google adwords call tracking feature.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var callback = function(formatted_number, mobile_number) {
          // formatted_number: number to display, in the same format as
          //        the number passed to _googWcmGet().
          //        (in this case, '1-800-123-4567')
          // mobile_number: number formatted for use in a clickable link
          //        with tel:-URI (in this case, '+18001234567')
          var e = document.getElementById("number_link_one");
          e.href = "tel:" + mobile_number;
          e.innerHTML = ""
          e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formatted_number));
        };
      </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var callback = function(formatted_number, mobile_number) {
          // formatted_number: number to display, in the same format as
          //        the number passed to _googWcmGet().
          //        (in this case, '1-800-123-4567')
          // mobile_number: number formatted for use in a clickable link
          //        with tel:-URI (in this case, '+18001234567')
          var e = document.getElementById("number_link_two");
          e.href = "tel:" + mobile_number;
          e.innerHTML = ""
          e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formatted_number));
        };
      </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var callback = function(formatted_number, mobile_number) {
          // formatted_number: number to display, in the same format as
          //        the number passed to _googWcmGet().
          //        (in this case, '1-800-123-4567')
          // mobile_number: number formatted for use in a clickable link
          //        with tel:-URI (in this case, '+18001234567')
          var e = document.getElementById("number_link_three");
          e.href = "tel:" + mobile_number;
          e.innerHTML = ""
          e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formatted_number));
        };
      </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var callback = function(formatted_number, mobile_number) {
          // formatted_number: number to display, in the same format as
          //        the number passed to _googWcmGet().
          //        (in this case, '1-800-123-4567')
          // mobile_number: number formatted for use in a clickable link
          //        with tel:-URI (in this case, '+18001234567')
          var e = document.getElementById("number_link_four");
          e.href = "tel:" + mobile_number;
          e.innerHTML = ""
          e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formatted_number));
        };
      </script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create a single function that you pass the id string to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array to iterate through the required strings:

```
var callback = function(formatted_number, mobile_number, number) {
      listofNumbers = ["one","two","three","four"]
      for(i=0;i<listOfNumbers.length;i++){
          var e = document.getElementById("number_link_"+listOfNumbers[i]);
          e.href = "tel:" + mobile_number;
          e.innerHTML = ""
          e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formatted_number));
      }
};
```

Alternatively, if the `callback` is called at different times, you could also 
add a new parameter to specify the ID used on line 8:

```
var callback = function(formatted_number, mobile_number, number) {
      // formatted_number: number to display, in the same format as
      //        the number passed to _googWcmGet().
      //        (in this case, '1-800-123-4567')
      // mobile_number: number formatted for use in a clickable link
      //        with tel:-URI (in this case, '+18001234567')
      var e = document.getElementById("number_link_"+which);
      e.href = "tel:" + mobile_number;
      e.innerHTML = ""
      e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(formatted_number));
};
```

Then, on future function calls, just use:

```
callback(formatted_number, mobile_number, "one"); //or "two", "three", etc.
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!